# No duplicate tags by category

Tags: query-posts, tags

I have script to show list tags from category and works very well.

```
<ul class="inline-list">
            <?php
                query_posts('category_name=lain-lain');
                if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    if( get_the_tag_list() ){
                        echo $posttags = get_the_tag_list('<li>','</li><li>','</li>');
                    }
                endwhile; endif; 
                wp_reset_query(); 
            ?>
          </ul>
```

It's possible to make no duplicate of tags and limit only 10 tags?

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! just install this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/linkify-tags/ then insert this script to theme `<?php c2c_linkify_tags('24, 9, 33'); ?>` and done!

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in the past project and this is my solution. I hope this is what you want.

```
       <ul class="inline-list">
            <?php
                query_posts('category_name=lain-lain');
                if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                    if ( get_the_tag_list() ) :
                        $count = 0;
                        foreach ( get_tags() as $value ) {
                            if ( $count>=10 ) 
                                break;
                            $output .= '<li><a href="http://example.com/tag/'.strtolower( $value->name ).'/">'.ucfirst( $value->name ).'</a></li>';
                            $count++;
                        }
                        echo $output;
                    endif;
                endwhile; endif; 
                wp_reset_query(); 
            ?>
          </ul>
```

Comment: hi @Puni, thanks for your time. Your code show 10 tags from all category, not from category "lain-lain" . In category "lain-lain" I have tags "lain1,lain2,lain3". Sorry if my instrution not very clear, actualy I want show only 10 tags per category. Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can have different tags under a category. Category and Tags are completely different. @user3232152